# Data structure: Is there something like a two way observer pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, data-structures, observer-pattern

So I have a scenario like this with classes Student and Course

Student A is enrolled in Course 1, 2

Student B is enrolled in Course 1, 2, 3

Student C is enrolled in Course 2

So there are two kinds of events:

Student A is deleted -> need to notify two objects: Course 1 and Course 2

Course 1 is canceled -> need to notify two objects: Student A and Student B

I know that the Observer pattern can work if each Student can be only enrolled in 1 Course, in which case I have a list of Student for each Course object in the Observer Pattern.

I am wondering if I should do some two way Observer Pattern (Student keeps a list of Courses and the Course also keeps a list of students). So would be a good way to deal with this problem? Main concern is speed/space tradeoff (what I can think of at best now is a two way hash/tree from 1 Student to 1 set of Courses and 1 Course to 1 set of Students). Any pointer will be appreciated!!

Comment: Why care about patterns? Just do your thing... At least in qt (examples) you often have an object and a widget associated to a property, which watch eachother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are really asking about is cascade semantics in a domain model. For instance, if a Course is deleted, should the students be deleted? Of course not. If a Student is deleted, should the Course be deleted? No.

I think what you might want to consider is another class: Enrollment. That says Student A enrolled in Course X on Date Y. Then if a course is Canceled, you cascade delete the Enrollments and then when you go to that Student to see what he's enrolled in, you don't see that Course anymore.

The additional benefit of this strategy is that if you want to retain the information (that he was enrolled and the Course was cancelled), that is there in the Enrollment class (which is an Association class).

Comment: But when a Course object is deleted, how do you walk thru all the Enrollment objects that corresponds to the course? Is there a fast way to do so? And what about when a Student is deleted?

Comment: You can do soft deletes (update a `deleted_at` type field) instead of real deletes so the rows are there, just not active. Same idea with the enrollments. In all honesty, the exact detail depend _strongly_ on the actual business requirements. Do the owners (you?) want the students there after delete? Do they want the enrollment history? etc

Comment: @user1141665 well if you use a persistence framework, it will do that, e.g. Hibernate or Core Data. No additional work required, and it will be atomic.

Comment: @JimDeville of course it depends on requirements. I am arguing for the more traceable approach with the association class.

Comment: @Rob, agreed. Didn't mean for my comment to imply criticism of your answer, meant to augment your answer to answer his question

Comment: A Student is not deleted, he just needs to be unsubscribed from a particular Course when that Course is deleted. Same for Course, when a Student is deleted, the Course needs to know too.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for bring up the Java framework, I don't have much experience with Java. After reading about the Hibernate framework, I see my problem as a "many to many" association. So I should better rephrase my question as a good way (data structure wise) to do that.