# How to efficiently design multi-key look up with one key being a vector of elements in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures

This question is more geared towards how to efficiently design this solution:
As an analogy to the problem I am trying to solve, consider that I have a list of students associated with each course.

Course A: List-of-students_1

Course B: List-of-students_2
....

Notes:

-> same students can be associated with multiple courses.

-> student list changes frequently

Now, there are 2 operations that I am supposed to perform here:

a). Have a functionality to have course specific announcements: in which case I need list of students enrolled in that course.

b). Have a functionality to query the all the courses that a student is enrolled in.

I looked at boost multi-index containers, but they won't solve the problem: my data is not "course:student" that can be sorted based on key; it's more  like "course:list_of_students" if one views it on a per course basis.

The closest design pattern (and I am very new to design patterns) was the observer pattern, but its more of a one way thing: I'll have to have a 2 way observer pattern to efficiently solve this issue.

Now, there was an existing thread having a similar question: [Data structure: Is there something like a two way observer pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594602/data-structure-is-there-something-like-a-two-way-observer-pattern)
The answers on it were not very satisfying. I'm not sure if it was a good idea to revive a year old thread or to start a new one, so I chose the latter.

Any help will be truly and sincerely appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "my data is not that can be sorted based on key"?  Can you be a lot more specific/precise about that?  Can your data be hashed if not ordered?  And which data, the course names or the student names?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: What I meant was, when you talk about multi-index containers, the key/index that we talk about are singular, not a list. If I am to perform a search based on the information that I have, it'll be applied on data in the form {course, list<students>}, and not {course, students}, which can be easily sorted for non-unique cases. Yes, my data can be hashed.

Comment: Don't students usually have unique student identification numbers?  How is it possible to have non-unique cases - every person must have some sort of a unique identifier?

Comment: @worker11811: Thanks for the response. I've posted a reply to your question on your post suggesting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
//   Sorted (any deterministic comparison) random access 
// collections of student and course descriptors/records
//
//   Insertion via binary search (SO search "c++ insert to sorted vector)

vector<student> students;
using students_t = decltype(students);

vector<course> courses;
using courses_t = decltype(courses);

// bidirectional student to course relation map
boost::bimap::bimap<
    multiset<students_t::size_type>,
    multiset<courses_t::size_type>
> assignments;
using assignments_t = decltype(assignments);
```

Or

```
// record must be inserted to students_t/courses_t before its enrollments_/subscriptions_ can be populated

struct enrolled_student {
    student student_;
    set<courses_t::size_type> enrollments_;
}

struct subscribed_course {
    course course_;
    set<students_t::size_type> subscriptions_;
}

vector<enrolled_student> students;
using students_t = decltype(students);

vector<subscribed_course> courses;
using courses_t = decltype(courses);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I think bimap is something that I might be able to use. I'll research a bit on it (memory footprint for many-to-many relations, etc.) and will get back to you in a couple of hours. The second approach will require more space/data-duplication for sure and hence will not take that route. Thanks again.

Comment: @Abi - #1 is my preferred too

Comment: The bimap will save my data as "one course: one student" relation, and this'll mean having a lot more memory as opposed to saving it as "one course: many student" relation considering that bimap internally maintains 2 maps with key value pairs for efficient lookup. I am trying to reduce the memory footprint here so (I believe) it'll not be the way to go.

Comment: @Abi - are you sure `bimap< multiset_of<>,multiset_of<> >` does not work? (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/discovering_the_bimap_framework.html)

Comment: don't misunderstand me, bimap surely works for the problem that I mentioned. However, the issue is that its memory footprint is too large. I was going through a blog explaining how it is internally implemented, and the author said that bimap internally maintains 2 maps for faster look up. This means that I'll have 2 entries in a map for each 'course-student' pair. This is even larger than the memory occupied by your second solution. I would certainly have gone with it had memory footprint not been that much of an issue.

Comment: Generally (though exceptions can exist) where a single collection<pair<int,int>> of pairs is fine two collection<pair<int,int>> are fine two . Did you measure the absolute values?

Comment: Thanks bobah! Yes, I measured the absolute values. For instance, for a single course and 2 students enrolled in it, the bimap will have the following entries: <course1, student1>, <course1, student2> for, say, the left map view. Since I want the right hand view as well, there'll be additional entries. I guess a better approach will be to put the course:student pair in a multi-index container sorted like you mentioned before. This'll mean saving the course:student pair once and information extraction will not be that expensive. Bobah, thanks a lot for taking the time out to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Something I would also consider is to look at this problem again:

Student lists changes frequently?  How frequently does it change?  Surely when students enroll for a course there is a cut-off time - after that you stay enrolled until the end of the course and can't enroll again.  Even if you can, how often does that happen?

Secondly the fact that the students can be enrolled to different courses isn't a problem or a problem definition,  I would rather say it is an attribute to the student.

Maybe look at creating an object for the course and let that have a list (vector) of students.  And create an object called student, which has a list (vector to the courses) he/she is subscribed to.

I think the problem here is that the solution you want is a lot more complicated than the actual problem.  Maybe look at redesigning it a bit.  If you need help with that, you can message me again.

It's a bit more of a philosophical answer, but it might help you a bit more in achieving your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Though I did mention it in my original post, I guess it got lost in the larger text of the post: the problem (course, student) stated above is ANALOGOUS to the issue that I am trying to address. I am working on a networking project and rather than explaining the intricacies of the actual project, I thought of picking up a simpler analogy to explain the issue at hand. The solution that you gave does address my issue, but I am trying to minimize the memory footprint of my solution.

Comment: ..contd: In the solution that you presented, I will be saving the same data twice: once w.r.t. the courses and once w.r.t the switches. Since I am relatively new to the world of designing, etc. I wanted feedback to see how smartly I can avoid saving this data twice and yet come up with an efficient solution. I might end up doing what you mentioned but again, as I said, I wanted to get a different opinion of how others see this issue. Thanks again for your input though.

Comment: @Abi you don't necessarily need to save it twice (the object I mean).  You can use pointers to the objects.  Even though the pointer is referenced twice, you still have one object.  I don't think that you will get away with it in another way.  If there are other designs, I would also gladly like to learn :)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I have for now. I have the courses:student_list saved in a data structure, and the shared pointer to these entries are saved in a separate struct as {student; shared_ptr<ptr_to "courses:student_list">}. Thanks again!